# Vaadin addon javascript not found in webpack

Tags: webpack, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I found the very promising looking VStepper addon for Vaadin 14+, but unfortunately I don't get it to run with Vaadin 20.

When adding some code using VStepper I always get an java.lang.IllegalStateException. Does anybody else have the same issues?

The problem is present with Tomcat 8. The addon is working with Springboot. v-stepper.js is added to node_modules/@vaadin/flow-frontend/ but the NpmTemplateParser is not able to find it.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find the definition of the element with tag 'v-stepper' in any template file declared using '@JsModule' annotations. Check the availability of the template files in your WAR file or provide alternative implementation of the method getTemplateContent() which should return an element representing the content of the template file
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.NpmTemplateParser.getTemplateContent(NpmTemplateParser.java:155)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.TemplateDataAnalyzer.parseTemplate(TemplateDataAnalyzer.java:217)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.TemplateInitializer.<init>(TemplateInitializer.java:100)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.PolymerTemplate.<init>(PolymerTemplate.java:94)
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.PolymerTemplate.<init>(PolymerTemplate.java:109)
    at com.mlottmann.vstepper.VStepper.<init>(VStepper.java:53)
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about how you run things that lead
(and lead not) to this error?  Can we assume, that "Tomcat 8" means
a standalone Tomcat where you have deployed the application?  And what
do you mean by "working with springboot" - as in using the embedded
server when running a fatjar or using some build-tool task?  You are
using a production build, right?

Comment: I can try to explain it in more detail:
"Tomcat 8" means a web war application deployed to tomcat 8 standalone using an IDE and maven build and non production mode as we are developing an application.
"Springboot" means the jar packaging starting the application with "debug as java application" on the ```@SpringBootApplication``` annotated class. Please also see the answer of @Limespace below as this is a further investigation of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

I have the same issue with spring-boot as well on Windows. Using an original vaadin starter download ( vaadin 20, java 8, flow-only) and adding the Addon I get the same error message.

A debug showed the same issue:

```
AbstractConfiguration.class
default String getFlowResourcesFolder() {
        return Paths.get(getBuildFolder(),
                FrontendUtils.DEFAULT_FLOW_RESOURCES_FOLDER).toString();
    }
```

returns `target\flow-frontend` on Windows and `target/flow-frontend` on Linux

Since the `BundleParser`

```
if (name.contains(FLOW_NPM_PACKAGE_NAME) || name.contains(service
                    .getDeploymentConfiguration().getFlowResourcesFolder())) {
                alternativeFileName = alternativeFileName.replaceFirst("\\./",
                        "");
            }
```

uses `String.contains()` to check if the leading "./" should be removed is fails in Windows but works on Linux (cause name is "../target/flow-frontend/v-stepper.js" )

---

I tried to debug this and found a mismatch in the folder name in the given webpack generated stats.js and the buildfolder returned by getFlowResourcesFolder()
which is "target\flow-fontend"
The name of the the module in stats.js is "../target/flow-frontend/v-stepper.js"

```
,{"id":"../target/flow-frontend/v-stepper.js","name":"../target/flow-frontend/v-stepper.js","source":"import { ....
```

This happens in flow-polymer-template-7.0.2.jar -> com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.BundleParser.getSourceFromObject(..) L:269

```
 if (name.contains(FLOW_NPM_PACKAGE_NAME) || name.contains(service
                    .getDeploymentConfiguration().getFlowResourcesFolder())) {
                alternativeFileName = alternativeFileName.replaceFirst("\\./",
                        "");
            }
```

[Snip of Debug Variable content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIhOH.png)

Environment is WIN10, Tomcat 8.5.x, Java 8, Vaadin 20.0.3, mvn build, vaadin NONE production mode, no spring

Comment: Further info: The addon it self is working with vaadin 20. I just imported (copied) all the sources into a simple test project and used VStepper and it showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the add-on doesn't support Vaadin 20 yet. I asked the author, but he doesn't have time to look into it right now.

Comment: I'm sorry, but as far as I understand the addon works perfect for Vaadin 14+ and this should also include Vaadin 20 shouldn't it? Why is it not possible to filter addons in vaadin addon repository then?Moreover it works when using springboot, but not when deploying to tomcat 8. Is this a known issue with Vaadin addons?

Comment: There is no automated validation for third-party add-ons when new Vaadin versions are released, so sometimes they break without noticing and further support needs to be added specifically.

Comment: ok, I understand that.
What I don't get is why it is still working with springboot using Vaadin 20 and not if using maven and tomcat 8.5.x?!

Comment: That would need further investigation, yes. If anyone figures it out before Matthias has time to dig into the problem I'm sure he would welcome a pull request or other help for the fixing. The repository is in https://github.com/mLottmann/VStepper